# Get rid of employee monitoring software

Tags: work-environment, work-experience

Nowadays in every company there is employee monitoring software installed on company laptops/computers.
Is it legal to crack or disable the monitoring software having in mind that employers don't notify employees or ask for permission for direct monitoring?

Can I legally ask my employer to stop monitoring my laptop?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118992/discussion-on-question-by-peter-penzov-get-rid-of-employee-monitoring-software).

Answer (score 5):

Not every company installs monitoring programs on their computers. For a properly secured network there is no need unless there is an investigation being carried out for a specific reason. And even then it's usually done in other ways such as just taking the machine off the employee.

If your company does this legally and you have an issue with it, it would be career limiting to crack it or otherwise interfere with it. You should approach your manager about your concerns.

The legality would be locale specific, so it's not something we can answer.